# ASP.NET MVC: Return Control via controller for ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Explanation of scenario:

I have a jquery window that will load up with a map control. This map control is a shared control in an asp.net MVC application. The way I've been told by Jquery developers is to use a $('').load(''); function to call into a controller which returns the control. Is this the best way? If so, how do i use the controller to return the control and in what format do i return it.

If this way is not right, could you please suggest an alternate way with tutorials to accomplish this please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create partial view containing this control and define action:

```
public PartialViewResult MapControl(params)
{
    //Prepare model
    return PartialView("PartialViewName", model);
}
```

Then you can use jQuery.load() method. How does this control work?

Comment: Its a map control. the user is supposed to select a location on the map and the control pass back addresses to the jquery window.

Comment: You just have to return html containing this control. How do you use it now? Show us some code containing map.